# Add CSS Class to Wordpress Menu Item Dependent on the Page the User is Visiting

Tags: menus, pages, sub-menu

I'm trying to have menu items show an underline under the related nav item when when the user on a specific page (image attached).

In the static site version of the site I'm doing I had a php variable at the top of each page such as:

`<?php $page = "home"; ?>`

Then in the menu item in the header, I did the following which added a 'page_active' class when someone is on the relevant page, which I could then style accordingly with CSS:

`<li><a href="./" class="<?php if ($page=="home"){echo 'page_active';}?>">HOME</a></li>`

Now I've moved it over to a custom WordPress theme this isn't working. I'm placing the variable above the `get_header()` function on each page:

```
<?php $page = "home";?>
<?php get_header();?>
```

Because this site has a couple of large submenus in the nav, using the `is_page()` function to detect the page url isn't going to work. For instance I have 11 submenu items under one of the main menu items.

** EDIT ** I've added two further pictures showing that when you click on one of the submenu items and got to a 'Practice Area' page, the parent 'Practice Area' menu item is underlined. This is from a static site version where I used the php code above.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: "large submenus" - are they custom links (e.g. `google.com`, `facebook.com`, etc.) or standard links like WordPress Pages, Terms/Categories, etc.? If so, then conditional tags like `is_page()` and `is_category()` should work fine.

Comment: @SallyCJ Hi they are WordPress pages, but I don't understand how using `is_page()` will work. I understand how to get it to work for straightforward menu items, but if I have 11 submenu items, and I want it so when someone visits one of those pages it shows the Parent Menu Item as underlined. E.g. in the new photos I've added, I want it so when if someone chooses a 'Practice Area' page when they land on this page the 'practice area' parent menu item is underlined. The examples given are on the static site & I just used the php code in the question. Thanks

Comment: check the difference in `<body>` class of the pages, you can them as selectors for CSS targeting. :-)

Comment: @TheChewy How is the menu created? Have you hard-coded it? Are using `wp_nav_menu()`? Do you use some plugin? Have you written a custom walker  for your menu?

Comment: @TheChewy With `wp_nav_menu()` you should get a whole bunch of default css classes, which you can use to detect which page is currently displayed, https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/#menu-item-css-classes

Comment: @TheChewy, "using the `is_page()` function to detect the page url" - I thought you're saying `is_page()` didn't work with the URL in the browser's address bar. And as @Antti said, if you're using `wp_nav_menu()` (with the default walker class), you could just use the relevant CSS class applied to the menu item; e.g. `.current-menu-parent > a { /* your CSS */ }`.